# How can I log in to my computer?

Tags: keyboard, language-support

Help! I changed my language on keyboard and I shut down my computer. Now keyboard doesn't work in English which I need to enter my password.

Comment: What language/locale did you set your keyboard to?

Comment: The local language is Amharic

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot access the Keyboard settings from the GUI, try running this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

You can find more info [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/changing-language-and-keyboard-layout-on-various-linux-distributions)

To boot as root, at grub select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" then boot in "Recovery mode".

At the "Recovery Menu", you can choose "Drop to a root shell propmpt":

[image: Running as root]

If your keyboard is working, although not in the correct keymap, you should be able to type the command.

Comment: How should the OP type that command, if English is not available?

Comment: He changed the language, it's probably a keyboard mapping issue. If I get the answer, the keyboard does work, but not with the en-US mapping. 
Also he can run the terminal as root using the failsafe settings from grub.

Comment: Boot with bootable USB drive, then chroot.

Comment: If you think there is a way, edit your answer, and elaborate. As is, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @mikewhatever, there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Being on Log On screen, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and it will take you to Terminal Screen.
2. In the terminal screen, type the login name and password.
3. Type the command, sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration.
4. Press Ctrl+Alt+F7 to get back to GUI mode.

Now, you can login as usually it was before.

Comment: I followed the steps and at the end came a command prompt. What do i do now?

Comment: If you have executed the command given in the third step, press Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return to GUI, that is Log on Screen. From there, you could proceed login process.

Comment: It doesn't still type in English

Comment: Did you run the exact command given in the step 3? Make sure each step what I have given. These steps will definitely solve you the issue.